# [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10013N The specified library "GSKit Error: 207" could not be loaded. SQLSTATE=42724 SQLCODE=-10013

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, db2, jupyter

I am trying to connect to IBM DB2 on Jupyter notebook, as in the attached images. But I'm facing an error:

> [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10013N  The specified library "GSKit Error: 207" could not be loaded.  SQLSTATE=42724 SQLCODE=-10013

I already installed ibm-db with pip and imported it. More information about my device:

- macOS                              Big Sur 11.2.3
- jupyter                            1.0.0
- jupyter-client                     6.1.12
- jupyter-console                    6.4.0
- jupyter-core                       4.7.1
- jupyter-packaging                  0.7.12
- jupyter-server                     1.4.1
- jupyterlab                         3.0.14
- ibm-cloud-sdk-core                 3.10.1
- ibm-db                             3.0.4
- Python                             3.8.10

Please help me. Thank you a lot.

[image: Pic 1: Import ibm_db and add params]

[image: Pic 2: Connect to db2 by ibm_db]

Comment: GSKit is the IBM Global Security Kit. The library should be installed with the CLI / ODBC libraries which the Python driver is based on. Please do not post your credentials, edit / remove the image

Comment: As this may be specific of MacOS 11.2.3, please open a ticket at https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: @StevenAlsheimer you can check the solution below

Answer (score 4):

Reinstalling the `ibm_db` and `ibm_db_sa` packages may help:

```
!pip install --force-reinstall ibm_db ibm_db_sa
```

Comment: worked fine. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-protect/8.1.9?topic=codes-global-security-kit-return, GSKit Error 207 means :
0x000000cf  207 GSK_ERROR_FIPS_NOT_SUPPORTED    This installation of GSKit does not support FIPS mode of operation.

It indicates about issue with certificate file. Another reason may be that your system already has some older version of GSKit installed at "C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8". If it is there, then it might be old. Better to rename this directory and then try. Thanks.