# pip install IBM_DB does not work on Ubuntu 22.04 python 3.8

Tags: pip, python-3.8, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install ibm_db v3.1.2 on python 3.8.13 Ubuntu 22.04 (5.15.0-40-generic)

```
pip install ibm_db


Collecting ibm_db
  Downloading ibm_db-3.1.2.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 5.5 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpfv417hua/output.json'
```

Other commands, such as `pip install numpy` work as expected

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I was able to work around the problem using Anaconda.
`conda install -c conda-forge ibm_db`. Now the basic use of ibm_db

`ibm_db.pconnect(connection_string, "", "")`

throws the error

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10013N  The specified library "GSKit Error: 207" could not be loaded.  SQLSTATE=42724 SQLCODE=-10013
```

which also seems to be [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487756/ibmcli-driver-sql10013n-the-specified-library-gskit-error-207-could-not-b), but the suggested solution does not work.

**Edit 2**: `pip3 install 'ibm_db==3.1.1'` worked, so the problem may be with 3.1.2

Comment: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/672

Comment: @phd It seems that the proposed solution still does not work on Ubuntu 22.04 python 3.8, as is mentioned in the referenced thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72871502/7976758

Comment: @phd Thanks. I replied to the solution mentioning that the proposed solution did not work for me, but installing an earlier version did