# Error with installing ibm_db with pip in venv in wsl

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, db2, wsl-2

Have to install ibm_db for a project as a requirement. But faced an error when installing it using the command `pip install ibm_db`. I am using a venv in wsl for the project.

Please help me out. Can't figure this error out on my own.

Tried deleting the folder as mentioned in another stackoverflow answer, but the folder `tmp5inyakrs` itself doesnt exist.

```
(venv) vishal@BatComputer:~$ pip install ibm_db
Collecting ibm_db
  Using cached ibm_db-3.1.2.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... -    '



done
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp5inyakrs/output.json'
```

Also, `getting requirements to build wheel` step takes atleast 20 - 25 mins, that isnt normal for sure, because I ran this project in an old laptop and there were no problems there.

python version - 3.8.10
distro version - Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Please edit your questions to give details, what is the distro version you are running? Did you try running `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `apt-get install python3-dev ` first before trying to install ibm_db ?  What is the python version?

Comment: Hi, I did install python3-dev, but I did not upgrade the pip. let me check that out and get back to you. thanks for the response. I updated the question with the versions you asked for, please check it out

Comment: @xBatmanx https://stackoverflow.com/q/72854801/7976758 , https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/672

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Comment: @phd i updated the question with error as code instead of image, i will check your previous comment's links out too. But just fyi, one of your links' answer  mentioned an issue with ibm_db-3.1.0, Im installing ibm_db-3.1.2. Does the error persist in this version as well?? Also, do you have any idea why its taking ages to get past the `getting requirements to build wheel` step?

Comment: upgrading pip fixed it, thanks to @mao !!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @mao 's Comment, try upgrading pip to see if that resolved the issue. That was the solution that worked for me. Thanks @mao

Comment: In my case upgrading pip did not work. However, installing an earlier version of ibm_db did. See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72854801/pip-install-ibm-db-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-22-04-python-3-8)

Comment: Maybe something to do with distro version? or that im using a venv?

Comment: No clue. I was using anaconda environment on anaconda 4.13.0, python 3.8.13, pip 22.1.2.